# What do electrumx peers do for the electrum server?

Tags: electrum, full-node, electrum-server

The documentation here https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peer_discovery.html explains how peers are announced to each other.  To run an electrumx server you need a full node to populate the database.  It makes sense that the clients can benefit from peer discovery and servers providing a peer list.  Is there any other role that the electrum server peers provide?  I am having a hard time find documentation on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few minor reasons why this might to useful for an electrum server:

- Knowing what block height / protocol version other peers are operating via [features advertised by peers](https://electrumx-spesmilo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-methods.html#server.features) to verify network issues
- Banning bad peers via [blacklisted peer list](https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/deep-dive-into-electrum-hack-reveals-70-of-network-was-controlled-by-attackers)